# No narrator voice during cutscenes in Borderlands on Xbox

Tags: xbox-360, borderlands

I have issue with lack of narrator voice on Xbox 360 version of Borderlands (first one, without any DLC). Claptrap in menu screams finely, buttons click, guns fire, music plays, Brick screams, Hunter coughs out his lungs while jumping... Just no narrator in cutscenes, no angel voice etc.

Xbox 360 Slim is fully updated, everything is legal, gold account is active, no overheating etc. I am trying to play 2 player coop.

Console is connected via HDMI 1.4 to full HD TV. Audio goes via HDMI as well.

I tried changing audio settings in Xbox settings but it had no effect.

So, how do I get narrator in cutscenes?

Comment: What cutscenes are you talking about?

Comment: A common reason why you can't hear voices is that the centre channel of a multilchannel soundtrack isn't working. In your case it may be because your sending multichannel audio to a TV that only has stereo speakers. Trying changing the audio settings so your console only outputs "Digital Stereo".

Comment: @RossRidge I tried all combinations of settings on both TV and console, no effect. I guess my next task is finding what TV I have, and now to play 5.1 on it.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue too, and I resolved it by setting my language to English and my region to US.